# MySQL Workbench. ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails. Operation failed

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1452

I can not bind a subordinate (Table administrator) and the main table (the department) by a foreign key.
It displays the following message:

Executing:

```
ALTER TABLE `grocery_supermarket_manager`.`administrator` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `AdministratorDepartment_FK`
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_department`)
  REFERENCES `grocery_supermarket_manager`.`department` (`id_department`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.

```
ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`grocery_supermarket_manager`.`#sql-9ac_8`, CONSTRAINT `AdministratorDepartment_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`id_department`) REFERENCES `department` (`id_department`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `grocery_supermarket_manager`.`administrator` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `AdministratorDepartment_FK`
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_department`)
  REFERENCES `grocery_supermarket_manager`.`department` (`id_department`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Column name: "id_department" table "Department" have:

- Datatype - INT(10)
- Storage: Primary Key, Not Null, Unique, Unsigned, Auto increment.

Column name: "id_department" table "Administrator" have:

- Datatype - INT(10)
- Storage: Not Null, Unsigned.

Comment: Please [edit] your code and exception into the question instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the current data in your table fullfills the constraint you are adding. Looks like you have administrators with invalid department ids.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!
The error was in the table administrator to id_department field. Invalid mentioned id department. Because of this, he could not establish a foreign key administrator (id_department) - Department (id_department)
I should be more careful.